# Passing arguments while running lodash flow asynchronously

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, currying, function-composition

Given the code below, how can I pass **id** to the **applySaveAsync** function?

```
   var then = _.curry(function (f, thenable) {
        return thenable.then(f);
    });

    var validateAsync = _.flow(
        function () { return _(someCondition).showError(ERROR_01).value(); },  
        then(function () { return _(anotherCondition).showError(ERROR_02).value(); }) 
    );

    var save = _.flow(
        validateAsync,
        then(applySaveAsync),
        then(saveCompleted)
    );

    function applySaveAsync(id) {
        // Saving...
    }

    save(22); // Calling save function with some id.
```

I can get the **id** on the **validateAsync** function, but I cannot return it back since **validateAsync** should return a promise.

Any way to achieve that?

Comment: I don' t think lodash curry & flow are promise aware.  And I'm not sure what they add to the table even if they were.  If you had save as a normal function the id would be captured (job done).

Comment: What do you mean "you cannot return it back"? As far as I can see your `validateAsync` function does return a promise that fulfills with the id. Where is your problem? Maybe show us more of your code.

Comment: @Bergi I have included the code of  `validateAsync `. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Keith I'm more interested in writing this code using functional programming, I know it can easily be solved using a normal function, or even exposing `id` as a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>The simplest choice would be not to use `_.flow` for the definition of `validateAsync`.</s>
Since `validateAsync` does not take parameters nor has a result, you should just change the definition of `save` to not use `_.flow`:

```
function save(id) {
    return validateAsync()
    .then(function(){ return applySaveAsync(id) })
    .then(saveCompleted)
}
```

We could also change `validateAsync` to pass through the `id`:

```
function validateAsync(id) {
    return _(someCondition).showError(ERROR_01).value()  
    .then(function () { return _(anotherCondition).showError(ERROR_02).value(); })
    .then(_.constant(id));
}
```

and even do that while still using `_.flow`

```
var validateAsync = _.flow(
    function(id) { return _(someCondition).showError(ERROR_01).value().then(_.constant(id)); },  
    then(function(id) { return _(anotherCondition).showError(ERROR_02).value().then(_.constant(id)); }) 
);
```

but I would advise against that since `validateAsync` is not supposed to be a function that does takes parameters.

Let's write a wrapper function for such instead to let us do the pass-around in a functional way:

```
function pass(fn) {
    return function(id) {
        return fn().then(function() {
            return id;
        });
    }
}
```

(if you prefer, you can try to compose that from `then`, `_.constant` and more)
so that one can write

```
var save = _.flow(
    wrap(validateAsync),
    then(applySaveAsync),
    then(saveCompleted)
);
```

Comment: You think there is no way to pass the `id` using composition? (I'm still learning fp).

Comment: @Anas see the edit. If you want to use composition, you need some way to pass the `id` through or around `validateAsync`. A large problem of `validateAsync` is that it is not pure (called only for side effects) and does not take an argument, which makes it compose very bad

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Comment: This is good. I made my 'then' function like this
```
const then = <T>(fn) => {
  return (input: Promise<T>) => input.then(fn);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this package useful for you. In Async cases, you can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@puzzleio/conductor).

Although flow is one of the best implementations for declarative programming, it doesn't support modern JS programming style.

```js
import { Conductor } from '@puzzleio/conductor';

const conductor = Conductor.createDefault();

const myAsyncWorkflow = conductor
  .add(validateAsync)
  .if({
    check: item => item.isValid === true,
    handler: item => console.log('Item is valid')
  },
  {
    // else block
    handler: item => console.log('Validation failed')
  });

myAsyncWorkflow.run(obj)
  .then(() => console.log('Successfully validated'))
  .catch(console.error);
```